# OpenGL ES 2.0 displaying objects in opposite depth order using LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, opengl-es-2.0, depth-buffer

I am using LibGDX and rendering a few models. This works as expected, except objects that are "further away" are displayed "in front" of "closer" objects. In other words the depth order seems to be the opposite of what I intended for it to be.

Strangely, the models are clipped in the correct order by the far clipping-plane. (Most distance objects disappear first)

I have tried enabling `GL_DEPTH_TEST`, and I am clearing `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: If you're using ModelBatch, it's redundant to manually call `gl.glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`, because the Model's Material will apply it by default. Are you using a custom Shader? Are your models transparent? Are you using any other OpenGL calls in between `modelBatch.begin` and `end`?

Comment: I am using `ModelBatch`, and I am using a custom shader. My models shouldn't be transparent. There is nothing but `modelBatch.render()` calls between `begin` and `end`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's always exactly the wrong order, check that you've passed something meaningful for [`glDepthFunc`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glDepthFunc.xml). The default is the usually sensible `GL_LESS`; try `GL_GREATER`.

If the order appears to be the order you're issuing draw calls then check that you actually have a depth buffer. It's hard to be more specific without knowing which LibGDX backend you're using but unless a depth buffer has been allocated then it doesn't matter what you do with the depth test, there's no storage for the buffer regardless.

Correct answer, as per twiz's comment below:

> I needed to set GL_LESS, but apparently LibGDX doesn't like it when
>   you use glDepthFunc(). My custom shader implements the Shader class,
>   so I had to use the RenderContext that is passed to the begin()
>   method. Then I added this line: context.setDepthTest(GL20.GL_LESS);

My guess would be that possibly LibGDX is doing something intelligent with threading and the appropriate context isn't set prior to calling the shader inits (or, possibly, LibGDX strictly wants you to use the explicit context rather than an implicit one and therefore goes out of its way not to have one be set — there's possibly a consideration of what can be threaded where in the future and a desire to keep the coding rules uniform). Just a random guess, of course.

Comment: I tried `glDepthFunc`, but it had no effect. It seem that the order might be an issue. I split each of my models into separate `ModelBatch` calls (each with a `begin()` and `end()`. When I did this, the depth seemed to be based on render order. Before I did this though, render order had now effect. 

Also, I think `GL_MORE` should actually be `GL_GREATER`.

Comment: And I am running this on my Linux desktop. If there is no depth buffer as you suggested, how do I go about fixing the issue?

Comment: Use http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Graphics.html#getBufferFormat-- and see what `depth` [buffer size] the `BufferFormat` indicates to check whether lack of a depth buffer could be to blame.

Comment: Here is the output of `getBufferFormat()`: `r: 8, g: 8, b: 8, a: 8, depth: 16, stencil: 0, num samples: 0, coverage sampling: false`

Comment: That would appear to imply that the absent depth buffer guess was wrong. I assume you've done nothing with `glDepthMask` or any other deliberate adjustment to the normal course of things?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Your first suggestion was actually pretty close.  For some reason I needed to set `GL_LESS`, but apparently LibGDX doesn't like it when you use `glDepthFunc()`. My custom shader implements the `Shader` class, so I had to use the `RenderContext` that is passed to the `begin()` method. Then I added this line: `context.setDepthTest(GL20.GL_LESS);`. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: BTW, if you feel the need for more points, you can edit this into your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've put the solution into the answer so that people are much more likely to find it in the future but marked it as community wiki so that I don't inappropriately get more points.