# Rendering multiple 3D Objects

Tags: opengl, 3d, libgdx, render

I'm learning how to render objects with libGdx. I have one square model, that creates a few model instance from them. If I have only one model it renders fine.
[image]

But if I have more instances it doesn't properly. Looks like the front objects are draw first, and the background the last one, so always the background objects are visible and the front objects you can see through them.
[image]

To render I use the following

```
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0,0,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mb.begin(cam);
    worldManager.render(mb, environment);
    mb.end();
```

mb variable is the ModelBatch instance, and inside worldManager.render each model instance is draw as follow:

```
mb.render(model, environment);
```

I'm not sure what is happening. But I think it is some GL attribute that I need enable

Is not 100% related to the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070612/opengl-es-2-0-displaying-objects-in-opposite-depth-order-using-libgdx) because, yes it uses OPENGL like libgdx, but the solution provided in that post is not working and I think the problem comes from ModelBatch from libgdx

[**Reproduction of the problem**](http://wklej.org/id/2285020/)

Comment: this one maybe `glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST)` ? It could also be that you enabled it, but didn't created the depth buffer, and everything works exactly as you didn't enabled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenGL ES 2.0 displaying objects in opposite depth order using LibGDX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070612/opengl-es-2-0-displaying-objects-in-opposite-depth-order-using-libgdx)

Comment: I flagged as duplicate, because it's opengl using libgdx and you got the same problem, so maybe the accepted answer would help you

Comment: Can't reproduce it using the information given. Please provide the information required to reproduce the problem you are trying to solve. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here is a new code I  wrote to anybody to reproduce the error. http://wklej.org/id/2285020/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't setup your camera correctly. First of all your camera's near plane is `0f`, which means it is infinitely small. Set it to a value of at least `1f`. Secondly you set the camera to look at it's own position, which is impossible (you can't look inside your own eyes, can you ;)).

So it would look something like:

```
camera = new PerspectiveCamera(90, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
camera.position.set(0, 10, 0);
camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
camera.near = 1f;
camera.far = 100f;
camera.update();
```

You probably want to start here: https://xoppa.github.io/blog/basic-3d-using-libgdx/

For more information on how the camera works have a look at: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1550

Btw, calling `Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);` will not help at that location and should definitely not be done when mixed with `ModelBatch`. ModelBatch manages its own render context, see the documentation for more information: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/ModelBatch

Comment: thanks the problem was on the camera. Yes i know that modelbatch has his own render context, that is why have thinking the problem was there and I try to enable depth_test on the modelbatch context. But the problems was the camera. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possible answer, but I would say that

```
glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST) ;
```

could help if you haven't done it yet. Also, enabling depth buffer only works if you actually have a depth buffer, which means you must makes sure you have one, and the method for this depends on your window context.

Comment: I enabled that line and still not working. I think the problem is from the ModelBatch from libgx. Also I put this line too and still not working batch.getRenderContext().setDepthTest(GL20.GL_DEPTH_BITS);

Answer (score 0):

for show the difference dimentions you can use the fog

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).